# Defining Constructor

Tags: apex, constructor

When I try to **run my codes** they keep on giving me an **error** saying **`Constructor not Define [testFBInt].<Constructor>()`**. I do not understand whats the problem and why it keep on giving me that error.

***Can someone help me to fix***

**Latest Modified Code**

```
public class testFBInt {


String username = myUsername;
String password = mypassword;
String clientId = Consumer_id;
String clientSecret = Consumer_key;
String tokenEndpoint = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';



public String requestAccessToken() {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(tokenEndpoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(buildHttpQuery(new Map<String, String> {
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => username,
        'password' => password,
        'client_id' => clientId,
        'client_secret' => clientSecret
    }));

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);

    Map<String, Object> m =
        (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp.getBody());

    return (String) m.get('access_token');
}

static String buildHttpQuery(Map<String, String> queryParams) {
    if (queryParams.isEmpty()) {
        return '';
    }

    String[] params = new String[] {};
    for (String k : queryParams.keySet()) {
        String v = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(queryParams.get(k), 'UTF-8');

        params.add(String.format('{0}={1}', new String[] { k, v }));
    }

    return String.join(params, '&');
}

public void exInt() {


String sessionId = requestAccessToken();

String dashboardImageURL = 'https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=.......';

String base64Data;
httprequest req = new httprequest();
req.setEndpoint(dashboardImageURL);
req.setmethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sessionId);
http http = new http();
httpresponse res = http.send(req);
Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);


Document docatt = new Document();
docatt.Name = 'Chart 1.jpg';
docatt.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
docatt.FOLDERID = '00l6F004101pqGi'; //Your folder id
docatt.IsPublic = true;

insert docatt;


 }

}
```

**Current Code Error** `Constructor not defined: [testFBInt].<Constructor>()`

---

**previously my Code was**

```
public class testFBInt {


String username;
String password;
String clientId;
String clientSecret;
String tokenEndpoint = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';

public testFBInt (String username, String password, String clientId, String clientSecret) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
}

public String requestAccessToken() {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(tokenEndpoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(buildHttpQuery(new Map<String, String> {
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => username,
        'password' => password,
        'client_id' => clientId,
        'client_secret' => clientSecret
    }));

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);

    Map<String, Object> m =
        (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp.getBody());

    return (String) m.get('access_token');
}

static String buildHttpQuery(Map<String, String> queryParams) {
    if (queryParams.isEmpty()) {
        return '';
    }

    String[] params = new String[] {};
    for (String k : queryParams.keySet()) {
        String v = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(queryParams.get(k), 'UTF-8');

        params.add(String.format('{0}={1}', new String[] { k, v }));
    }

    return String.join(params, '&');
}

public void exInt() {

//String sessionId = upf.requestAccessToken();

String sessionId = requestAccessToken();

String dashboardImageURL = 'https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=.......';

String base64Data;
httprequest req = new httprequest();
req.setEndpoint(dashboardImageURL);
req.setmethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sessionId);
http http = new http();
httpresponse res = http.send(req);
Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);


Document docatt = new Document();
docatt.Name = 'Chart 1.jpg';
docatt.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
docatt.FOLDERID = '00l6F004101pqGi'; //Your folder id
docatt.IsPublic = true;

insert docatt;


 }

}
```

**Error Message**

`Constructor not defined: [testFBInt].<Constructor>()`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57408/discussion-on-question-by-luke-au-defining-constructor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a constructor with 0 parameters, so you need to use the 4-parameter version:

```
testFBInt upf = new testFBInt (
'my_user_name',
'mypassword',
'Consumer_key',
'Consumer_secret'
);
```

Also, having that code inside your class will result in infinite recursion (stack overflow exception), so make sure you don't do that.

Comment: So both ways I tested the codes are wrong?

Comment: @LukeAu Taking out the code I copy-pasted in the first version should fix your class. Everything else looks okay off the top of my head.

Comment: And fixing this line: `String sessionId = requestAccessToken();`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using below code:

```
testFBInt upf = new testFBInt (
'my_user_name',
'mypassword',
'Consumer_key',
'Consumer_secret'
);
```

I believe due to above code, it gives you error.
just replce it with below code:

```
public testFBInt (){}
```

Please have a look and let me know

Comment: if I replace the method with `public testFBInt(){}` is there any other way to get my value for `String sessionId = upf.requestAccessToken();`?