# System.LimitException: Maximum stack depth reached: 1001 Error

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, execute-anonymous

I'm not sure Why I'm getting this Error Message without any indication of what line is the error from.

I remove the parameter from the Constructor because I'm planning on shifting this code to the **scheduler** and the scheduler **won't allow me** to add a class that have a constructor with parameter.

***Can someone help me fix it?***

---

**Error Message**

```
System.LimitException: Maximum stack depth reached: 1001
```

---

**Code**

```
global class testFBInt {


String username = 'username';
String password = 'password';
String clientId = 'consumer_id';
String clientSecret = 'consumer_secret';
String tokenEndpoint = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';

public testFBInt () {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
}



global void Execute(){

String sessionId = requestAccessToken();
exInt(sessionId);
}

public String requestAccessToken() {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(tokenEndpoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(buildHttpQuery(new Map<String, String> {
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => username,
        'password' => password,
        'client_id' => clientId,
        'client_secret' => clientSecret
    }));

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);

    Map<String, Object> m =
        (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp.getBody());

    return (String) m.get('access_token');
}

static String buildHttpQuery(Map<String, String> queryParams) {
    if (queryParams.isEmpty()) {
        return '';
    }

    String[] params = new String[] {};
    for (String k : queryParams.keySet()) {
        String v = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(queryParams.get(k), 'UTF-8');

        params.add(String.format('{0}={1}', new String[] { k, v }));
    }

    return String.join(params, '&');
}


 @future(callout=true)
 public static void exInt(string sessionId) {




String dashboardImageURL = 'https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=.....';

String base64Data;
httprequest req = new httprequest();
req.setEndpoint(dashboardImageURL);
req.setmethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sessionId);
http http = new http();
httpresponse res = http.send(req);
Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);


Document docatt = new Document();
docatt.Name = 'Chart 1.jpg';
docatt.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
docatt.FOLDERID = '00l6F005101pqGi'; //Your folder id
docatt.IsPublic = true;

insert docatt;

System.Debug('@@ doc ' + docatt);
}
}
```

---

**Error When Debugging from Developer Console**

[image]

---

**Developer Console Code**

`testFBInt s = new testFBInt();
 s.Execute();`

Comment: This was already answered here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170843/defining-constructor - sfdcfox's answer specifically addressed this specific issue. I believe your question should be how to use the class??

Comment: @Eric I *thought* that looked familiar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
testFBInt upf = new testFBInt ();
```

When you construct a new instance, this line is called, which constructs a new instance, which calls this line...

You don't need to initialize an instance of the object as it's constructed, because you can refer to the current instance using the keyword "this".

Comment: then means I can't request for my access token? from this line `String sessionId = upf.requestAccessToken();`?

Comment: @LukeAu Just call requestAccessToken, it will use the current instance (this is an instance method).